# Create a Windows shortcut that behaves like the actual file

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, file-shortcut

I have file A. I need to put it in folder B but I update it from another folder where things are centralized. For obvious reasons, .lnk shortcuts don't behave like symlinks. Is there a way to create a shortcut that will give the actual file when called? Breakdown:

- Program calls file in X:\Folder B\File A
- Magic symlink masquerading as X:\Folder B\File A has Program access file at X:\Central Repo\File A instead
- World Peace Achieved

How do I create such a magic symlink?

Comment: Forgive me for asking a stupid question: but have you tried a symlink? I think you should step back to the original problem and give us that. You've made some assumptions, but links and symlinks and files are all operating and file system level things and just making up a new thing doesn't happen overnight. We need to get back before those assumptions so we can understand the original problem and solve that.

Comment: Oh my god I feel so dumb. How did I completely gloss over the fact that symlinks exist on windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should be able to use a directory symlink.  That's what I do. The caveat is that the filename has to remain the same.

```
mklink /D NewName OriginalFoldername
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that symlinks exist on Windows.

```
mklink NewName OriginalName
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the other answer? If the other answer works and you want to express your gratitude, please just accept the other answer.

Comment: It symlinks a file instead of the entire directory. I have other files in Folder B